# Url Regax error in Firefox browser

Tags: angular

I am working in angular 2 application and i am putting

> pattern="^[(http|https|ftp|)://|[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.a-zA-Z?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-._\?\,\'/\+&%\$#\=~])*[^.\,)(\s]+"

for website validation. it is working fine in crome and IE but getting error in firefox.

Comment: Could you please add the actual error message?

Comment: <input pattern='^(http|https|ftp|)\://|[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z](:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&%\$#\=~])*[^\.\,\)\(\s]$'> because the pattern is not a valid regexp: invalid identity escape in regular expression